# Detemining Odd and Even values with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have below some IP addresses and I want to categorize them based on their last digits.

An IPv4 address consists of four numbers:

- each of which contains one to three digits(0-255)
- with a single dot (.) separating each number or set of digits

Now I want to refer the last digit of an IP address and if it was `[Odd]` the related columns fulfilled with Odd and if it is `[Even]` it would fulfill with even.

```
IP Address          
192.168.1.1         #last digit is 1 and consider it as odd
192.168.1.2         #last digit is 2 and even
192.168.152.200     #last digit is 200 and is even
192.168.54.98       #last digit is 98 and is even
192.168.98.93       #last digit is 93 and is odd
 .....
 ......
```

Expected Result:

```
IP Address                 Status
192.168.1.1                Odd
192.168.1.2                Even
192.168.152.200            Even
192.168.54.98              Even
192.168.98.93              Odd
........ 
........
```

Comment: take the last number, then use the modulus operation. if `n % 2 is 0`, then is even.

Comment: I am new to pandas and regex, would you mind please share with me the code.

Comment: I believe this has nothing to do with regexes. I feel you can do this by [taking the last part of a string](https://www.bing.com/search?q=python+substring&cvid=314134c1834d41eca42f3868a3463005&pglt=547&FORM=ANAB01&PC=U531) and using basic arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"IP Address" : 
["192.168.1.1",
"192.168.1.2",
"192.168.152.200",
"192.168.54.98",
"192.168.98.93"]})
```

df:

```
        IP Address
0      192.168.1.1
1      192.168.1.2
2  192.168.152.200
3    192.168.54.98
4    192.168.98.93
```

```
df['New-variable'] = df['IP Address'].apply(lambda x:"Odd" if int(x.split(".")[-1]) % 2 else  "Even")
```

df:

```
        IP Address New-variable
0      192.168.1.1          Odd
1      192.168.1.2         Even
2  192.168.152.200         Even
3    192.168.54.98         Even
4    192.168.98.93          Odd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
IPList = ["192.168.1.1",
    "192.168.1.1" ,       
    "192.168.1.2",         
    "192.168.152.200",   
    "192.168.54.98",      
    "192.168.98.93" ]      
final_list = []
for ip in IPList:
    _ip = ip.split(".")
    if int(_ip[-1]) %2==0:
        final_list.append([ip,'Even'])
        continue
    final_list.append([ip,'Odd'])
df = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns =['IP Address', 'Type']) 
df
```

Output:

```
    IP Address      Type
0   192.168.1.1     Odd
1   192.168.1.1     Odd
2   192.168.1.2     Even
3   192.168.152.200 Even
4   192.168.54.98   Even
5   192.168.98.93   Odd
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `df` is called x, you can do this:

```
import numpy as np
# First remove the '.' so that you can convert to float
x['IP_num'] = (x['IP'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([ch for ch in x if ch.isdigit()]))).astype(float)
# Then create a new column if the IP is odd / even
x['even_odd'] = np.where(x['IP_num'] % 2 == 0,'Even','Odd')
```

Output:

```
                IP             IP_num even_odd
0      192.168.1.1      19,216,811.00      Odd
1      192.168.1.1      19,216,811.00      Odd
2  192.168.152.200 192,168,152,200.00     Even
3    192.168.54.98   1,921,685,498.00     Even
4    192.168.98.93   1,921,689,893.00      Odd
```

you can drop the 'IP_num' column if you want.

Comment: Wonderful, I understand Completely.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

This is just displaying the input:

```
import pandas as pd

adr_df = pd.DataFrame(['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.152.200', 
                        '192.168.54.98', '192.168.98.93'], columns=['IP Adress'])
```

One example if you really like to use **regex** for capturing the last digit, you could use the following command (be careful in escaping the dot-char with `\.`):

```
adr_df['Last Nr'] = adr_df['IP Adress'].str.extract(r'.*\..*\..*\.(.*)').astype(int)
```

Of course, there could be more exact regex-strings to match the ip, but this one works for me.

Checking for odness you can reach with a small lambda function:

```
adr_df.loc['Status'] = adr_df['Last Nr'].apply(lambda x: 'Odd' if x%2 else 'Even')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here loops by `for` or `apply` are not necessary - extract values after last `.`, convert to integers, use `% 2` and last pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['IP Address'].str.split('.').str[-1].astype(int) % 2,'Odd','Even')
    
print (df)
        IP Address   new
0      192.168.1.1   Odd
1      192.168.1.2  Even
2  192.168.152.200  Even
3    192.168.54.98  Even
4    192.168.98.93   Odd
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df
```

[image]

```
df['Status'] = [int(str(x).strip()[-1]) for x in df['IP Address']]

df['Status'] = np.where(df['Status']%2, 'Odd', 'Even')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can `extract` last digits and then use methods `divmod` and `map`:

```
df['IP Adress'].str.extract('(\d+)$', expand=False).astype(int)\
.divmod(2)[1].map({1: 'odd', 0: 'even'})
```